# Can *ne* in *ne ... quidem* mean *ne* instead of *non*?

Tags: classical-latin, example-request

In all examples I have seen, the *ne* in *ne … quidem* could be replaced with *non* alone, leaving out the *quidem* (thus changing the meaning from "not even" to "not"), and still make a grammatically correct sentence but not with *ne*.

Are there examples in classical literature where the *ne* in *ne … quidem* could be replaced with *ne* alone, leaving out the *quidem*, and still make a grammatically correct sentence?
I would like to see an authentic example to convince myself that this is possible, assuming it is.

Let me try to illustrate what I'm looking for by an artificial example.
First, consider this simple example with *non* and *ne*:

> *Non hodie canis.* — *Spero, ne hodie canas.*
>   You do not sing today. — I hope that you will not sing today.

Let us then add *quidem*:

> *Ne hodie quidem canis.* — *Spero, ne hodie quidem canas.*
>   You do not sing today, either. — I hope that you will not sing today, either.
>   (For both statement and hope: You usually don't sing and today is no exception.)

I have seen various examples of structures like *ne hodie quidem* which mean *non hodie* but have the *quidem*.
What I have never seen is *ne hodie quidem* in a clause where you would expect *ne* instead of *non* if you drop the *quidem* (for example, introducing the conjunctive in a prohibition, fear or danger clause).
Using the word *hodie* is not important, of course; I am looking for *ne … quidem* with anything in between.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe I have found at least one example where *ne...quidem* replaces what would otherwise just be *ne*:

> in foribus scribat occupatam ésse se.
>   aut quod illa dicat peregre allatam epistulam,
>   **ne epistula quidem ulla sit** in aedibus
>   nec cerata adeo tabula;  (Plautus, *Asinaria*, IV.1)

Comment: This is a good find! I won't object to having more examples, of course, but this already satisfies my main curiosity.

Comment: Though in this case it seems like *quidem* is focused on *ulla* rather than *epistula* —which in a weird way makes this seem not quite like an occurrence of *ne...quidem* (in the sense that *ne...quidem* applies as a rule to the word between the two elements).

Comment: Excellent find. It's worth pointing out, though, that Old Latin syntax isn't necessarily the same as Classical Latin syntax; many usages that are found in Plautus aren't found in later writers, and this may or may not be one such.